# How to access remote db data in Ruby on Rails?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails-5, mysql-workbench

I am having mysql in my local application and our client has given a sample application db access where we can find more seed data.
Now my question is there anyway of accessing the client data by changing any database.yml file in my local?
I tried using workbench -> Data export, I am getting the following error:

mysqldump: Got error: 1045:Access denied for user 'un'@ip-address  (using

> password: no) when trying to connect
>
> Operation failed with exitcode 2

Is there any way to access the remote data without exporting?

Answer (score 0):

you have to provide the ip address as host and all the login credentials to access it, also make sure you are inputting correct values. First check your connection by testing it on workbench then put values in yml file.

```
default: &default
adapter: mysql2
pool: 5
timeout: 5000
port: 3306

development:
  <<: *default
  database: <database name>
  host: <ip address>
  username: <username>
  password: <password>
  socket: <socket> or /tmp/mysql.sock
```